# как сделать, чтобы к новому коментарию добавлялось текущее время

Tags: javascript, angularjs, время, angularjs-controller

как сделать, чтобы к новому коментарию добавлялось текущее время

```
`https://codepen.io/agafron/pen/xLajQy`
```

это моя попытка, но она добавляет время первого комента ко всем остальным, как это исправить?

Comment: пожалуйста, приложите код непосредственно в тело вопроса. Внешние сервисы не всегда доступны, код там может изменится или удалится вовсе со временем. более того это требует лишних переходов отпользователей, и если на десктопе это еще не такое дорогое с точки зрения удобства и времени операция, то в мобильных приложениях и мобильном браузере это делать крайне неудобно. Также неудобно и отвечать на ваш вопрос смотря на код в другом сервисе(и тут речь идёт о всех устройствах). Уважайте отвечающих - приложите код в тело вопроса. Сниппеты для HTML/JS/CSS в редакторе имеются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот здесь уберите `vm.time` и замените на `new Date()`:

```
vm.resetComment = function() {
 vm.newComment = {
    nameCommentator: "anonymous",
    date: new Date(),
    description: null
}};
```

Comment: Лучше все-таки использовать `Date.now()`

Comment: Намного быстрее работает

Comment: спасибо! все оказалось так просто, что аж зло берет!)))

Comment: @Herrgott, благодарю за подсказку! Приму к сведению.

Comment: @user264945, пометь ответ как правильный, пожалуйста.